# Wyverns on console? (terraria)

Tags: terraria-console

So i just recently got into hardmode... And i've found about 4 arch wyverns and they all killed me with like 3 hits. I really want wings but i just cant kill these guys, are there normal wyverns on console or only archs?

I have a pirate cutlass(though i dont melee it...)
and a laser rifle from the wall of flesh, along with my trusty pheonix blaster with tons of meteor shots, i have a good 46 def.

So do normal wyverns spawn on console?

Answer (score 1):

I have Terraria on my Xbox One and remember the regular wyverns  (the white ones) spawning. The [Wiki for wyverns](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wyvern) doesn't say that they don't spawn on console. The arch wyverns however seem to be console/mobile exclusive. The might explain why you see them more.

It also recommends waiting until you get better weapons, as they are quite difficult for someone who just entered hard mode to take on (though you listed that you have a decent setup already).  Try playing with friends if you can and teaming up on them.

I've also read that nearby NPC's can affect spawn rates of them.  I don't know if you have any nearby but if you do, try and move further away.